Self-homeomorphism of a punctured sphere extends to homeomorphism of the whole sphere?
Suppose $A\subset S^2$ is a finite set of $n$ points. Let $f: S^2\setminus A\to S^2\setminus A$ be a homeomorphism. Is it true that $f$ admits an extension to a homeomorphism $g:S^2\to S^2$ such that $g(A)=A$ and $g|_{S^2\setminus A}=f$?
I think the answer is "yes." My intuition is that you can take a set of pairwise disjoint circles $C_i$ around each puncture $a_i\in A$ and consider their homeomorphic images $C_i'=f(C_i)$. The set $\{C_i: i=1,\dotsc, n\}$ and the set $\{C_i': i=1,\dotsc, n\}$ are in bijective correspondence and both constitute a set of generators for $\pi_1(S^2\setminus A)$. Within the interior of each of these circles, $f$ is essentially a homeomorphism from a punctured closed disk to another punctured closed disk. The question then reduces to whether a homeomorphism $f:\overline{D^2}\setminus\{(0,0)\}\to \overline{D^2}\setminus\{(0,0)\}$ with $f(S^1)=S^1$ extends to a homeomorphism with $f(0,0)=(0,0)$. I think this should follow from some variation of the Alexander trick but I am not sure.
Does this seem like it's on the right track or is there an obvious problem I am missing? If it makes a difference, I actually only hope for this result to be true when $|A|\geq 3$, so if it is true in this case but not in general then please let me know.

Your approach seems reasonable to me. If you don't want to talk about the end compactification, you can finish your proof by only knowing about the one-point compactification. The point being that the closed disc is the one-point compactification of the punctured closed disc, and a homeomorphism $X \to Y$ always extends to a homeomorphism of the one-point compactifications. This is easier than Alexander's trick - the point is that an open nbhd of $0$ in the closed disc is exactly the same as the complement of a compact subset of the punctured disc, so the extension will be continuous at $0$.

It's easier than all that. Simply use the end compactification functor. For any closed surface $S$ and any finite set $A \subset S$, the end compactification of $S-A$ has a natural homeomorphism to $S$. Also, any homeomorphism of any space extends naturally to a homeomorphism of its end compactification.

Do you happen to have a reference that discusses this variation of end compactification? The wikipedia article only mentions that it is a functor to the category ${\bf Set}$. I would like to see some details for the continuity of the extension if possible.

This link does define the topology on the end compactification.

And here is someone's blog on the topic which seems to have detailed proofs.
